# Alternative to Dialog.setOnShowListener in Android api level 7

Tags: android

Does anyone have an idea of an alternative to using the new (as of api level 8) Dialog.setOnShowListener.  I would like to adjust some things in the calling activity based on the measured height of the dialog, but in order for that to work, I need access to the measured height of the dialog.  It works fine in an OnShowListener() callback, but I'd like to find a solution that will work on api level 7.

Comment: Do you need it to be a `Dialog`? Or can it be a `Dialog`-themed `Activity` instead? You have a bit more flexibility with the `Dialog`-themed `Activity`.

Comment: That's an option on the table, I guess, but I was hoping for something simpler that I could just drop in.  This is intended to be an api level 7 project, and somebody accidentally used setOnShowListener to implement a visual feature, and I'd like to preserve the feature and not have to re-write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I ended up taking was to override the onLayout for the root layout object in my dialog, and then perform my necessary adjustments in there.  Works fine.